# How to dynamically create access database with date field having custom date format?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Can anyone please help me on my current problem?

I am doing a project that dynamically creates access database (.mdb file). the database have a date field but I want it to have custom date format.

Here is what I have so far.

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source =" & databaseName)
        con.Open()
        Dim dbSchema As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, _
                                                            New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, tableName, "TABLE"})
        con.Close()
        If dbSchema.Rows.Count > 0 Then
'I have some code here
        Else
'This is where I create the table
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE [" + tableName + "] ([Meter] TEXT(2), [Name] TEXT(20), " _
                                              & "[Element1] TEXT(20), [Element2] TEXT(20), [Element3] TEXT(20), [W] TEXT(20), " _
                                              & "[pf] TEXT(20), [kWh_Delivered] TEXT(20), [kWh_Received] TEXT(20), " _
                                              & "[Date_Time] Date(mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss))", con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Table Created Successfully")

        End If
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have work around my problem.I did not get to solve my problem but instead I work around the code that needs that value and there I replaced the format. 
Thanks anyway.